# Spotting small patterns in images

Tags: keras, convolution

When using convolution, one often has recognize big objects in images like elephants or dogs. The first convolutional layers then recognize edges, the last layers focus on more abstract features like legs or body shape.

The task I'm currently working on is different: I have images of the size 512x512 with black/white scans of documents. I don't need to recognize text or some other complex patterns, but rather need to find things like inkblots. The network should just learn if there is anything like that or not.

Usually, I'm using structuring my networks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer((512, 512, 1))

for size in [32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 512, 512]:
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Conv2D(size, (3,3), 'relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(size, (3,3), 'relu'))
    model.add(AveragePooling2D())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, 'sigmoid'))
```

This is the structure I commonly use and tried for this use case, but my results are not overwhelming, which is why I'm questioning my structure. If I only need to recognize the existance of patterns, which can have the size 5x5 or 30x30 tops, should I use a different structure?

Comment: I think you should try hyper parameter tuning.All we can make is educated guesses.But hyper parameter tuning is the best way to find it out.